# Facebook PHP SDK v4.0.0: $session is not set even after authorizing facebook from the login URL

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

UPDATE: The problem is now solved. All what I did is to put this code in a **different** php file:

```
<?php
Function __autoload($classname) {
    $filename = "./".$classname .".php";
    require_once($filename);
}

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

session_start();

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('257772307761170','***');

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/parqueeste/login.php');
try {
  $session = $helper->getSessionFromRedirect();
} catch(FacebookRequestException $ex) {
  // When Facebook returns an error
} catch(\Exception $ex) {
  // When validation fails or other local issues
}
if ($session) {
  echo 'Yeah!!';
}
?>
```

Original message: I'm using the Facebook SDK v4.0.0 for PHP to create a "Login through Facebook". But even after the user clicks the login URL, the $session variable is not defined so I can't access the user's data. Here's my code:

```
<?php
session_start();
function __autoload($classname) {
    $filename = "./".$classname .".php";
    require_once($filename);
}

use Facebook\FacebookSession;
use Facebook\FacebookRequest;
use Facebook\GraphUser;
use Facebook\FacebookRequestException;
use Facebook\FacebookRedirectLoginHelper;

FacebookSession::setDefaultApplication('257772307761170','****'); //I have the right
app secret on my code, of course.

$helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/parqueeste/');
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();


if(isset($session) AND $session) { // <--- I use isset() so I don't
get a warning everytime I load my site

  try {

    $user_profile = (new FacebookRequest(
      $session, 'GET', '/me'
    ))->execute()->getGraphObject(GraphUser::className());

    echo "Name: " . $user_profile->getName();

  } catch(FacebookRequestException $e) {

    echo "Exception occured, code: " . $e->getCode();
    echo " with message: " . $e->getMessage();

  }   

}
?>
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Technically you also moved the `start_session()` method to where I said to move it.

Comment: Glad you were able to solve it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The actual issue here is that when you call the getLoginUrl() method e.g

```
 $helper = new FacebookRedirectLoginHelper('http://localhost/parqueeste/');
 $loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl();
```

It changes the state variable. In your original question (before you edited it to include your fix) you called this method **before** you validate the response in your original code, it then invalidates the CSRF check and in short says the user hasn't logged in. I ran into this exact same issue, and the best bet is to either have a separate login page as you have done here. Or to have the login url generated after you've done all the checks for a valid session/graphobject response.

Hope this helps some else who has the same issue as it annoyed me for days and isn't really documented and is a big change from the previous api. You need to look through the SDK to see what's going on

Comment: Thank you for tour answer! I'd vote up, but I can't.

Answer (score 2):

I experienced this issue myself. You need to start a session using `session_start();` in your script for it to work correctly. [See my short tutorial for more information](https://www.webniraj.com/2014/05/01/facebook-api-php-sdk-updated-to-v4-0-0/).

Add it to the top of you script, I did it just after the `use` statements.

Comment: @Niraj Shah Your article was a godsend !! Thanks a lot.Wish i had come across your blog a little earlier.